# How to sum specific item in json arrray object, linq prefer on C#

Tags: c#

Hi I'm working on Json Deserialize Object on C# using json newton. Below is my code.

```
 transactions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TransactionClass>>(response.Content);
```

And returned results.

```
      [
        {
         "id":1,
         "school_uuid":"d17eab20-a442-11e9-928b-cb6a3dc8f7ea",
         "student_id":1,
         "actiontype":"1",
         "total":100,
         "created_at":"2019-07-12 01:54:45",
         "updated_at":"2019-07-12 01:54:45"
        },

        {
         "id":2,
         "school_uuid":"d17eab20-a442-11e9-928b-cb6a3dc8f7ea",
         "student_id":1,
         "actiontype":"1",
         "total":100,
         "created_at":"2019-07-12 01:55:28",
         "updated_at":"2019-07-12 01:55:28"
        }
     ]
```

I would like to sum for item `total`, In this case `sum = 100 + 100 = 200`. It work fine on looping method. But I prefer shorter like linq instead. Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: [Are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561312/) [you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29325589/) [too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554926/) [lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641682/) [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230268/) [do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978736/) [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417623/) [google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717858/) [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250991/)?

Comment: Dear vasily.sib , Thanks for answer.

Comment: @joenpcnpcsolution - Don't forget to use the `@` notification system so that your recipient gets notified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;

int sumOfTotals = transactions.Sum(transaction => transaction.total);
```

Read this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Dear cdev, Thank you very much.

Comment: @cdev - Is there something in your "Read this" that you think is important for your answer?

Comment: Dear Enigmativity, Thanks for more info.